# html files parsed as php but shown as html

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website which has a bunch of simple HTML pages.  There is a menu in the page and of course the html is repeated across all the pages.  I want to be able to put the menu in a php file and then have it as an include in all html files.

I thought I could do this with .htaccess by getting all html files parsed as php.  However I'm having real problems getting it to parse.  I've been tons of google links and have tried a bunch of stuff but none of it seems to work  any ideas:

stuff I've tried:

```
            # Use PHP5.4 as default

            AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm 
            AddHandler php-script .php .html .htm
            AddHandler php5-script .php .html .htm
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm 
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .html



            AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .html .htm

            AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php .html
```

Not all at once but line by line.  None of it worked!  The server uses fast cgi so I think actually only the addhandler stuff is needed and it uses 5.4.4

thanks

Comment: There's a really simple answer to this question, use files with the .php extension instead.

Comment: @adeneo - there are issues with that solution. If the site is established, and depending on the number of pages, you'd need not only rename them all, but then update the links across the website. The correct usage of processing HTML files as PHP depends on the server, for some you'd need to use `AddHandler cgi-script .html   
SetEnv PHP_EXTENSION .html`

Comment: @GeoffAtkins -  I tried the addhandler cgi ... and it gives a forbidden error .  This feels like a step forward?  any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer in the comment (which I shouldn't have done) had the linebreak removed.

Some hosts (including the one I use for their shared servers) have Linux configured differently. You might want to speak with them or check their support documentation, they may have answered it for you.

For my host, this is the correct pair of commands to have PHP execute within files that have a .html extension.

```
AddHandler cgi-script .html 
SetEnv PHP_EXTENSION .html
```

Comment: Thanks - is it possible to exclude directories (and their subdirectories) from this directive?

Comment: Yes, add another .htaccess file to the directory that removes those directive `RemoveHandler cgi-script .html`.